# Using binding conventions for ninject on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ninject

I am using ninject to get my dependencies in a windows phone application. I come from a structure map background where I used to scan all the assemblies in the application directory and get all the implementations by naming conventions such as IMyObjectType would correspond to MyObjectType.

Now I am trying to achieve this using ninject but I have two problems here: one problem is the fact that I need to use ninject to scan and inject instances and two, I am on windows phone and there are no assemblies as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an assembly reference a loop trough all the classes and interfaces in that assembly without any problems also on Windows Phone:

```
foreach (var type in (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract)
    {
           //registers the type for an interface it implements
    }
}
```

I wrote a whole blog post about this: http://blog.kulman.sk/automatic-viewmodels-and-services-registration-for-not-only-caliburn-micro/